# Parentheses between \big and \Big

Tags: amsmath, delimiters, parentheses

Is there a way to create parentheses in math mode that have an extension between that of the commands `\big` (too small) and `\Big` (too big)? The amsmath package documentation defines the delimiters in this way:

```
\renewcommand{\big}{\bBigg@\@ne}
\renewcommand{\Big}{\bBigg@{1.5}}
\renewcommand{\bigg}{\bBigg@\tw@}
\renewcommand{\Bigg}{\bBigg@{2.5}}
```

but if I try with something like

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\Pbig}{\bBigg@{1.25}}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble and then I write `$\Pbig($` in the code, it doesn't work; it only produces the same results as `\big` or `\Big`.

Comment: a font only offers a fixed set of designed delimiters then for larger sizes constructs arbitrary size by inserting a straight extender segment. So for the smaller sizes the only option is to load the font at a different size if the supplied sizes are not as required.

Comment: Depending on the application, the `scalerel` package might help.  Please give a more firm example of desired usage.

Comment: I simply have to put a mathematical expression in brackets; like, for instance `$[a + bx]$`. The problem is that `\bigl[` is too short to include all the mathematical text, whereas `\Bigl[` results to long.

Answer (score 10):

Here I use `scalerel` package to create a delimiter that is `1.5pt` larger above and below (3 pt total) than `\big` .  I call it `\pig`.  I limit the overall width to `5pt`

While it will technically "work" with any delimiter, it is really intended for either `(` or `\{`.  Use with `[` produces an undesirable line thickness.  EDITED to minimize this issue and provide two alternatives.

In this manifestation (the intermediate size is a scaled up `\big`), the bracket line thickness is slightly too thick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\newcommand\pig[1]{\scalerel*[5pt]{\big#1}{%
  \ensurestackMath{\addstackgap[1.5pt]{\big#1}}}}
\newcommand\pigl[1]{\mathopen{\pig{#1}}}
\newcommand\pigr[1]{\mathclose{\pig{#1}}}
\begin{document}
$ \bigl( \pigl( \Bigl($

$ \bigl\{ \pigl\{ \Bigl\{$

$ \bigl[ \pigl[  \Bigl[$ $<$---BAD!
\end{document}
```

[image]

In this second manifestation, one `\big` is changed to `\Big` in the `\pig` definition (so that the intermediate size is a scaled down `\Big`), and the maximum width was increased to 5.5pt.  Now, the bracket line thickness is just slightly too thin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\newcommand\pig[1]{\scalerel*[5.5pt]{\Big#1}{%
  \ensurestackMath{\addstackgap[1.5pt]{\big#1}}}}
\newcommand\pigl[1]{\mathopen{\pig{#1}}}
\newcommand\pigr[1]{\mathclose{\pig{#1}}}
\begin{document}
$ \bigl( \pigl( \Bigl($

$ \bigl\{ \pigl\{ \Bigl\{$

$ \bigl[ \pigl[  \Bigl[$ $<$---BAD!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps one of the versions is [almost] suitable.

Comment: +1 for `\pig`. :-)

Comment: @Mico My original implementation had `\cig`, but I started thinking, "`\pig` seems much more appropriate in so many ways!"

Comment: The code works fine, but the problem is that a I really need the square bracket. ;)

Comment: @TFra6 Please see my edit to minimize the issue.  Two alternatives provided.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the second example. Let's say that until now it's the best solution I've found, so I'll take this one. However, the best idea to avoid these small subtleties would be to know how the `\big`, `\Big`, etc. delimiters are defined in LaTeX and from there define an 'equal' one simply by changing the numbers (if possible). But I do not know how I can do it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can I directly replace \big by your size? without changing the command to pig?

Comment: @mnmn1993 Yes, I think you should just be able to use `\pig`, `\pigl`, and `\pigr` directly as you would with `\big`...